# How can I count the number of zero decimals in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

How do I get the number of zero decimals behind the comma (but not the total)? So to illustrate an example:

```
0.00001 > 4
0.000015 > 4
0.0000105 > 4
0.001 > 2
```

I am looking for methods that are efficient (meaning that they optimize the calculation time).

Comment: are those values in string format or float?

Comment: It is float. So far I only tried it with a for loop, but does not seem efficient for me.

Comment: @JohnAndrews It doesn't *seem* efficient? Have you measured it? Is it too slow for the task it's meant for?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use logarithms to find the magnitude of the number:

```
var x = 0.00195;
var m = -Math.floor( Math.log(x) / Math.log(10) + 1);
document.write(m); // outputs 2
```

Later versions of JavaScript have [Math.log10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10), so it would be:

```
var x = 0.00195;
var m = -Math.floor( Math.log10(x) + 1);
document.write(m); // outputs 2
```

How using the base-10 logarithm of the numbers works:

| x | Math.log10(x) | Math.floor(Math.log10(x) + 1 ) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1 | -1 | 0 |
| 0.01 | -2 | -1 |
| 0.015 | -1.8239… | -1 |
| 0.001 | -3 | -2 |
| 0.00001 | -5 | -4 |
| 0.000015 | -4.8239… | -4 |
| 0.0000105 | -4.9788… | -4 |

Comment: Just as a heads up, this returns `-0` for `0.195`. In case that really matters.

Comment: That is fine. Really like this answer, exactly what I was looking for. Something smart.

Comment: @RGraham Which browser are you using? I get 0, not -0, in  IE11 and FF38 on Windows.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Chrome 43

Comment: Nice one, Andrew! I'd comment that code though to clarify what it does - it wasn't evident to me at first. :)

Comment: @TedNyberg It isn't intended to be production-ready code: it's missing a check for `x > 0.0 && x < 1.0`.

Comment: Did a nice bench on my answer below if you are interested. your answer seems fastest so far.

Comment: @TedNyberg Sorry, it took me a little while to respond to your comment. Does the table offer enough explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Use this one:

```js
function numberOfZeros(n) {
  var c = 0;
  while (!~~n) {
    c++;
    n *= 10;
  }
  return c - 1;
}

document.write(numberOfZeros(0.00065));
```

This code does the following: it multiplies the number by ten as long as it can be truncated to something not equal 0. The truncation operator "~~" is very performant, because it works with byte representation of the number directly.

It doesn't use any string operations and does exactly what you want: counts the zeros.

Comment: Careful, if you call it with n=0 it will get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

```js
    //my answer
    function t1()
    {
        var num = 0.0000005323;
        numOfZeroes = 0;
        while(num < 1)
        {
            numOfZeroes++;
            num *= 10;
        }
    }
    
    //others
    
    //Andrew Morton's answer
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002148/1115360
    function t2()
    {
        var num = 0.0000005323;
        var m = -Math.floor( Math.log10(num) + 1);
    }

    //Amy's Answer
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002087/4801298
    function t3()
    {
        var r = 0.0000005323;
        var count=0;
        var splited = r.toString().split(".")[1];
        for(var i=0;i<splited.length;i++)
        {
            if(splited[i]==0)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }    
        }
    }

    //Ted's Answer
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002052/4801298
    function t4()
    {
        var number = 0.0000005323;
        var numberAsString = number.toString();
        var decimalsAsString = numberAsString.substr(numberAsString.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
        var leadingZeros = decimalsAsString.substr(0, decimalsAsString.lastIndexOf('0')+1).length;
    }

    //Bartłomiej Zalewski's answer
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31001998/4801298
    function t5()
    {
        var n = 0.0000005323;
        var c = 0;
        while (!~~n) {
            c++;
            n *= 10;
        }
        return c - 1;
    }

    //Andy 's answer
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002135/4801298
    function t6()
    {
        var float = 0.0000005323;
        var zeros = float.toString().match(/(\.0*)/)[0].length - 1;
    }

    //Praveen's answer
    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002011/4801298
    function t7()
    {
        var a = 0.0000005323;
        return (a.toString().replace("0.", "").split("0").length - 1);
    }

    //benchmark function
    function bench(func)
    {
        var times = new Array();
        for(var t = 0; t < 100; t++)
        {
            var start = performance.now();
            for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                func();
            }
            var end = performance.now();
            var time = end - start;
            times.push(time);
        }
        
        var total = 0.0;
        for(var i=0, l=times.length; i<l; i++)
            total += times[i];
        var avg = total / times.length;
        return avg;
    }

    document.write('t1: ' + bench(t1) + "ms<BR>");
    document.write('t2: ' + bench(t2) + "ms<BR>");
    document.write('t3: ' + bench(t3) + "ms<BR>");
    document.write('t4: ' + bench(t4) + "ms<BR>");
    document.write('t5: ' + bench(t5) + "ms<BR>");
    document.write('t6: ' + bench(t6) + "ms<BR>");
    document.write('t7: ' + bench(t7) + "ms<BR>");
```

**Note:**
This would only work with numbers less than 1 of course. Otherwise, just remove numbers left of the decimal point first, like

```
num -= num % 1;
```

need to compare this to another way.

**a while later...**

I would like a better way to bench these function though. I might have my calculation wrong. I'm adding other peoples answers into the test. I'm now attempting to use the performance API

**a bit later than before**

AHA! Got it working. Here are some comparisons for you.

Comment: Where are the comparisons? In the [hidden reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001901/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-zero-decimals-in-javascript/31001998#31001998) - Bartłomiej Zalewski's answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Running the code snippet will give you live results using your local browser. each function is named t1-t6. each being a different user's response. I'm not sure if i have every user's response here since i made this quite a while ago and have updated it from time to time

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex to match the number of zeros after a decimal point and then count them.

```
var zeros = float.toString().match(/(\.0*)/)[0].length - 1;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/am3pouqt/4/)

Comment: what if a number is 0.000105. Then I get 4 zeros but it should be only 3.

Comment: No, you don't. See the demo.

Comment: Error if using:
`var float4 = parseFloat('1');`

Fix by checking for validity:
`console.log(float4 ? float4[0].length - 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
function num (a) {
  return (a.toString().replace("0.", "").split("0").length - 1)
}
```

Comment: what if a number is 0.000105? Then I get 4 zeros but it should be only 3.

Comment: True, your requirement is different. Not just number of zeroes. It should be no of zeroes in the front. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example (a bit lengthy for clarity):

```
var number = 0.0004342;

var numberAsString = number.toString();

var decimalsAsString = numberAsString.substr(numberAsString.lastIndexOf('.')+1);

var leadingZeros = decimalsAsString.substr(0, decimalsAsString.lastIndexOf('0')+1).length;

// leadingZeros == 3
```

Comment: Another example would be to convert decimalsAsString to int and then back to string and compare the difference in length (as all the leading 0's would have been removed by the int conversion).

Comment: Yes it is, so if this is done repeatedly (for large number series) I'd probably go for something else. But since this use case is a bit uncommon, I'd strive for understandable code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number in to a string and split it with the dot (.). Using the *for* loop to count the zeros occurrences.

```
var r = 0.0000107;
var count=0;
var splited = r.toString().split(".")[1];
for(var i=0;i<splited.length;i++)
{
    if(splited[i]==0)
    {
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
    
}
console.log(count);
```

Comment: As I pointed somewhere else, I don't think doing string operations is performant.

Answer (score 0):

## Node.js 9.0.0

I was looking for a solution without converting or the O(n) approach. Here is what solution I made by O(1).
Part of finding decimal by log – caught from @AndrewMorton, but it might be laggy with the divider: log(10) – 2.302585092994046.

#### Example

```js
const normalize = (value, zeroCount) => {
  const total = 10 ** zeroCount
  const zeros = Math.floor(-Math.log10(value / total))
  return value * (10 ** zeros)
}
```

### Usage

```
normalize(1510869600, 13) // 1510869600000
normalize(1510869600, 10) // 1510869600
```

Comment: A bit late, but node.js has [supported Math.log10](https://node.green/) since before V4, so you could use `const decimalZeros = Math.floor( -Math.log10(value / total) )`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton nice, I have updated the answer